# Move root partition from one disk to another in Debian 10

Tags: grub2, debian-buster

I have installed Debian 10 on a hard disk in a partition in a logical volume(name: deb10). Now I want to move the running installation to a logical volume on a SSD(name: deb10ssd).

1. I copied the files from the old to the new partition (with rsync running on another debian installation on a different disk).
2. I changed the copied fstab to reflect the new root.
3. I ran update-grub and grub-update (which found the new installation)

When I boot I see in the boot menu the new installation (deb10ssd). when I select it, the system boots properly but ends up in the old root disk (deb10, not deb10ssd).

what additional steps are necessary to inform grub to boot from the new root device?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to re-run `update-initramfs -u` to pick up the fstab changes. This would need to be done while chrooted in the new system. You could boot a debian installer in rescue mode to set up the chroot for you.

Comment: I have no experience with `chroot`. what would be the least confusing and most secure way? I would greatly appreciate pointers; what I have found is confusing. The alternative is to reinstall debian and packages.